# Java unhandled Exception

Tags: java, android-studio, exception, compiler-errors

I'm currently developing an Android app using Android Studio and I encountered an error that I can't understand. Here's an example of my code :

```
public class MyClass {

    public void method1() throws MyException {
        methodIO();     // Unhandled Exception: java.io.IOException
        methodRun();    // OK
    }

    public void method2() throws Exception {
        methodIO();     // OK
        methodRun();    // OK
    }

    public void methodIO() throws IOException {}

    public void methodRun() throws RuntimeException {}
}

class MyException extends Exception {

    public MyException(){super();}

    public MyException(String message, int errorCode) {
        super(message);
    }
}
```

I can't figure out why in method1(), I have the following error "Unhandled Exception: java.io.IOException" while method2() compiles fine. The issue doesn't appear with a method throwing a RuntimeException even if both classes are inheritd from Exception. Does someone know what's going on here ?

Ps : I'd like to avoid using a try/catch bloc or adding a new  `throws` clause

Comment: "my methods are normally returning values." That doesn't preclude the use of try/catch.

Comment: Yeah for sure. I just want to undestand what's wrong here to be honest. I'll easily find a way to do this with a try/catch bloc indeed

Comment: "I'd like to avoid using a try/catch bloc or adding a new  throws clause" Those are your only 2 choices if you want to call `methodIO`. (The only other choice is not to call the method.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MyException` doesn't extend `IOException`, so the `IOException` thrown by `methodIO` isn't handled currently.

It works in `method2` because `Exception` is a common superclass of `IOException` and `MyException`, so it specifies how both types of exception should be handled.

Add it to the `throws` clause of `method1`:

```
public void method1() throws MyException, IOException {
```

or catch in the method body:

```
public void method1() throws MyException {
  try {
    methodIO();
  } catch (IOException e) {
    // Handle appropriately.
  }
}
```

Comment: I'd like to avoid using a try/catch or adding throws clauses to my code. I edited my question and added a method throwing a RuntimeException. Everything is working fine with the method throwing en RuntimeExceptionwhereas I have the error with the method throwing th IOException. Yet, both RuntimeException and IOException are inherited from Exception.

Comment: If you call a method which throws a checked exception (subclasses of `Exception` which aren't subclasses of `RuntimeException`), you **have to** either try/catch it or add it to the method's `throws`; you have no choice in Java, that's just the way checked exception handling works. `RuntimeException` (and its subclasses) are unchecked exceptions, so you don't need to explicitly handle them.

Comment: OK thanks, I didn't know this concept of checked and unchecked Exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

`method2()` has a throws declaration for the base type `Exception`, of which `IOException` is a derived type; whereas `method1()` throws a `MyException`, which `IOException` does not derive from. Add `IOException` to the throws declaration of `method1()`:

```
public void method1() throws MyException, IOException {
    methodIO(); 
}
```

or you could always catch the `IOException` and throw a `MyException` instead:

```
public void method1() throws MyException {
    try {
        methodIO(); 
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new MyException();//construct MyException however; this is just an example
    }
}
```